# Rewrite rule for start of url

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite all urls that start with a predefined language and move the language to a param.

For example:

**example.com/de/home to example.com/home?lang=de**

**example.com/en/home to example.com/home?lang=en**

I have this rule in my Apache config file

```
RewriteRule     ^/?(en|de)/(.*)$        $2?lang=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

The problem is it fires multiple times:

**example.com/en/en/home to example.com/home?lang=en**

**example.com/en/de/en/de/home to example.com/home?lang=en**

How can I limit the rule to just one occurrence of the language?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is the issue. The `?()`:

```
 ?(en|de)
```

is a non-capturing group. To capture, remove the `?`:

```
 (en|de)
```

**References**

- [PCRE Man Page](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt)
- [RewriteRule Flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html)